# Gridview DataKeyNames subclass property

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview bound to a list of objects like so `List<myObject>`.

The object has property which is a child object - an `Address` object.

I want to add the PostCode property of the Address object to the gridview's DataKeyNames property like so: `DataKeyNames="Id, Address.Postcode"`, but keep getting the error **myObject does not contain a property with the name Address.Postcode** (it does...)

Any ideas?

---

EDIT: To clarify, I cannot modify myObject so that it exposes the Postcode as a property like so: myObject.Postcode. The Postcode property needs to sit where it is in the Address object (myObject property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do it like this, it should be like..

```
DataKeyNames="Id, Postcode"
```

You need to get the PostCode column in your datasource object which you are going to bind to your Gridview.

Comment: I've tried that already. I get the error message myObject does not contain a property with the name 'Postcode'.

Comment: As I have told you in answer, you need to get PostCode column in your datasource which you are going to bind to your Gridview.

Comment: Are you saying I have to modify my object so it looks like myObject.Postcode?

Comment: I am not sure, but can you try "Id, myobject.Address.Postcode" ?

Comment: This answer looks like the only way to do it. In the end, I just removed the Postcode from the DataKeyNames and got it out of my List<myObject> (using the 'id' DataKeyName)